# VirtualBox set up Ubuntu machine no bootable medium found

Tags: virtualbox

I was trying to set up my ubuntu machine using VBoxGuestAdditions.iso located in `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox`, which I believe is default location for all VBoxGuestAdditions.iso. However, after I confirmed the setting, I will encounter error when I started the machine as : `no bootable medium found, system halted.`

For alternative, I downloaded the ubuntu 16.04 disk image and use it as disk image I can start my machine smoothly. But the only problem is I can no longer use copy-and-past even I set up the bidirectional shared-clipboard.

How should I fix the first and second issue ?

Comment: I don't understand why you are running a 16.04 Live environment "for alternative." As an alternative to what, exactly?

Comment: So in the setup page, I was asked to choose disk image. I can either choose VBoxGuestAdditions.iso or the ubuntu 16.04 disk image. The default is VBoxGuestAdditions.iso.

Comment: Neither of those is an "alternative" to the other. Each does something very different. Are you trying to install Ubuntu? Or are you trying to use *both* Live (not installed) Ubuntu and Guest additions at the same time? And why ancient 16.04?

Comment: I am actually not sure what guest additions does. I just want to have a ubuntu machine, so I think I need to install Ubuntu. 16.04 is because I am more used to ubuntu of this version in the company.

Comment: Step 1: Install Ubuntu. Ignore Guest Additions. Step 2: After install is complete, poweroff the Guest machine. Remove the Ubuntu installer .iso from the Virtual CD Drive. Add the Guest Additions .iso to the Virtual CD Drive. Step 3: Boot into the installed system, now with Guest Additions.

Comment: Sounds good, just to confirm, so I should run the ubuntu 16.04 iso file to start my machine, and install the ubuntu (instead of try ubuntu) for the step 1 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113010/discussion-between-exteral-and-user535733).

Comment: If you goal is to install, then select the install option. If your goal is something else, then sometimes Try Ubuntu might be appropriate. Advice: If you are unsure what Guest Additions does, then omit it until you know exactly why you want it.

Comment: So where should I add Guest Additions .iso ? Should I add it in settings/storage/optical dirve and select cd/dvd ? Don't know why I still cannot use copy and paste after inserting with vboxguestadditions.